# No module named 'rake_nltk'

Tags: python, nltk, metadata, rake

from rake_nltk import Rake

def generate_ai_keywords(text):
# Initialize Rake object
rake = Rake()

```
# Extract keywords from the text
rake.extract_keywords_from_text(text)

# Get the top 10 keywords with scores
keywords_with_scores = rake.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()[:10]

# Extract only the keywords without scores
keywords = [keyword for score, keyword in keywords_with_scores]

# Append domain-specific AI keywords
ai_keywords = ['artificial intelligence', 'machine learning', 'deep learning', 'neural networks', 'natural language processing', 'computer vision']
keywords += ai_keywords

return keywords
```

## Example usage

text = "Artificial intelligence is a fascinating field that has gained a lot of attention in recent years. It involves the development of intelligent machines capable of performing tasks that typically require human intelligence."
keywords = generate_ai_keywords(text)
print(keywords)

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SIRI\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 1, in 
from rake_nltk import Rake
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rake_nltk'

---

NOTE : I INSTALLED RAKE MODULE WHILE I'M INSTALLING IT RAISING AN ERROR LIKE

---

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip